Delete item from pgSTAC - using psql or pypgstac
I'm working with a pgSTAC database and trying to figure out how to remove two specific items. I've loaded items using pypgstac, but didn't see a way to accomplish a delete operation with that tool.
So, I opened a psql shell into the database and tried running DELETE FROM pgstac.items WHERE id NOT LIKE '%bananas';. This threw the confusing error
NOTICE:  Updating partition stats 2024-04-10 22:07:41.678482+00
ERROR:  type "geometry" does not exist
LINE 13:     extent geometry;

This comes from a trigger function on the pgstac.items table:
Triggers:
    items_after_delete_trigger AFTER UPDATE ON items REFERENCING NEW TABLE AS newdata FOR EACH STATEMENT EXECUTE FUNCTION partition_after_triggerfunc()
    items_after_insert_trigger AFTER INSERT ON items REFERENCING NEW TABLE AS newdata FOR EACH STATEMENT EXECUTE FUNCTION partition_after_triggerfunc()
    items_after_update_trigger AFTER DELETE ON items REFERENCING OLD TABLE AS newdata FOR EACH STATEMENT EXECUTE FUNCTION partition_after_triggerfunc()

I noticed the trigger functions on items are mis-named (_after_delete runs AFTER UPDATE & visa versa)  but don't know if the actual content of the trigger function is incorrect.
Is there a better way to handle this? I'd be happy to use pypgstac or psql.
